# How to use a repository's pull request as dependency in pubspec.yaml file?

Tags: flutter

I want to import a package's specific pull request, for example, [this one](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/pull/967). I wish I could do:

```
dependencies:
  permission_handler:
    git: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/pull/967
```

Comment: The PR isn't part of the URL, it's a reference. If flutter lets you specify `refs/pull/967/head` as a ref, use that. If not, use a hash ID as shown in [Islom Rixsiyev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74937755/1256452).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can need to use `ref` and give it the value of the commit.

```yaml
dependencies:
  permission_handler:
    git: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler.git
    ref: a73ec3f5164bbc21ad0a9748ab58e862fb80b12f
```

Answer (score 5):

Please check this format.

```yaml
dependencies:
  permission_handler:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler.git
      ref: a73ec3f5164bbc21ad0a9748ab58e862fb80b12f
```